# I am taking my laptop for repair. How do I secure it as much as possible?

Tags: security

Is it enough to just create a very strong password for Ubuntu login or I need to do something else? I just want to make sure they will not be able to access my files / logins etc. while repairing my screen.

Comment: Depending how paranoid you are, the best way is to remove the drive.  No drive no access.

Comment: @crip659 That sounds like a good answer. I had this idea myself a while back. You could remove the hard drive and provide them either a different hard drive or just give them a USB with a live installer on it and tell them to use the "try Ubuntu without installing" option.

Comment: You can test it out with an external monitor (if you have one) to see if there's any problem booting from a USB.

Comment: My computer guy destroys hard drives from computers that he gets for reselling or trashing.  Data can only be hidden not erased.  Money and know how can find it.

Answer (score 0):

If it's your screen being repaired, consider removing the harddrive before hand.  This suggestion makes three assumptions

1. The harddrive is removable
2. You have enough confidence to open the case - in which case you might be able to perform the screen repair your self
3. There is another bootable drive (such as a DVD) in the unit.  The repair people are going to want to boot something to verify the screen repair.